# How to prevent bash environment variables from autoconverting to absolute path while using envsubst?

Tags: bash, yaml

I am working on a shell script and need to replace some parameters in a `.yaml` file. I am using `envsubst` command but instead of getting the exact output, the leading `/` in one value is converted to absolute path which I do not want.

The file I am working on, `test.yaml` is as given below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-azuredisk
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: ${SIZE}Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: managed-csi
  csi:
    driver: disk.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: ${VALUE}
    volumeAttributes:
      fsType: ext4
```

I am using `envsubst` command to replace `${SIZE}` and `${VALUE}` parameters as follows:

```bash
value="/some/handle/for/volume"
size=20

export VALUE=$value SIZE=$size

echo "$(envsubst '$VALUE:$SIZE' < ./test.yaml)"
```

The leading `/` in `/some/handle/for/volume` is converted to absolute path i.e., `${VALUE}` is replaced by `C:/Program Files/Git/some/handle/for/volume`.

Is there any way to tell `bash` or `envsubst` to not consider this value as a path and just as a string?

1. I did experiment and calling `echo $VALUE` after export gives `/some/handle/for/volume` which might mean `envsubst` is causing this problem.
2. I did try a `export VALUE="$value" SIZE="$size"` as suggested by [@Lea Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7939871/l%c3%a9a-gris) but it results in the same problem.
3. ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:
   I am able to achieve what I want by using `sed` command to replace the elements, however that command is not convenient if I want to deal with multiple replacements, so I would still prefer to solve this with `envsubst`.
4. PROBLEM (MOST PROBABLE)
   Looks like this problem only exists with bash on windows and the translation. From what I understand, I will not get this issue on linux. Will test it out and see.

Comment: So this looks like bash on windows like git bash?

Comment: Yes @Jetchisel, this is exactly `Git Bash`

Comment: How about not using the Command Substitution? Does it still have the same output? Or try using a subshell for the code in questions.

Comment: @Jetchisel I tried those things, so I tried running just `envsubst '$VALUE:$SIZE' < ./test.yaml`, and I also tried with paranthesis `()` ( I think that runs the code in a subshell ).

No luck. Same output with autoconversion to absolute path.

Comment: The original path is absolute, too. The weird substitution sounds like a Cygwin or Mingw problem. Getting rid of Windows is always a popular recommendation.